# Error en entity framework 6 al usar el comando enable-migrations

Tags: entity-framework

Tengo un error al momento de generar el **enable-migrations** en la consola del administrador de paquetes que solo se suscita en una maquina que tiene w7 instalado, en las demás maquinas todas tienen windows 10 y el mismo visual studio 2019 basicamente al momento de hacer la generacion haciendo uso de ese comando me arroja el siguiente error que muestra a continuacion.

> PM> enable-migrations El término 'enable-migrations' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa e
> jecutable. Compruebe si escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó
> una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha  ruta es correcta e inténtelo
> de nuevo. En línea: 1 Carácter: 18
>
> - enable-migrations <<<<
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (enable-migrations:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Revisando el archivo me encuentro lo siguiente

```
# Functions to export from this module, for best performance, do not use wildcards and do not delete the entry, use an empty array if there are no functions to export.
FunctionsToExport = (
    'Add-EFDefaultConnectionFactory',
    'Add-EFProvider',
    'Add-Migration',
    'Enable-Migrations',
    'Get-Migrations',
    'Update-Database'
)
```

La única diferencia çcreo yo que radicaría es que en la w7 no tengo instalado el sql server a diferencia de las de w10, pero no creo que seria valido esto porque estoy haciendo uso una conexión a un bd que apunta a azure sql.

Espero que me den su puesto de vista y me puedan ayudar cual es mi problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

asegúrate de tener instalado el Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools en el proyecto que seleccionaste al momento de ejecutar el comando, si no lo tienes lo puedes hacer via NUGET

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

Puedes probar igual actualizandolo, en dado caso lo tengas

```
Update-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

De lo contrario, podrias probar instalar el sql considerando que los migrations de alguna forma trabajando a la par, de igual forma si no encuentras alguna mejora, podrías restablecer tu Visual

Comment: Es valido el usar Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Toolsm ya que estoy haciendo un proyecto de aplicacion web asp.net framework?